# How to add a static block to every page

Tags: magento-1.9, css, static-block

I want to add a static block to the header and footer to add custom CSS ( head area ) and JS to footer area.

I'm doing this so if i want to add custom CSS I don't have to edit files and upload them via FTP. I can just edit the static block and it's there instantly

My CSS static block is called inline-css  and JS one is inline-js

Any help would be great. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have already one, create a file called `local.xml` in your theme (`app/design/frontend/<your-theme>/default/layout/local.xml`) with the following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
             <block type="cms/block" name="inline_css" as="inline_css">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>inline-css</block_id</action>
             </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="footer">
             <block type="cms/block" name="inline_js" as="inline_js">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>inline-js</block_id</action>
             </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```